# 500 Internal Server Error on Subversion Commit

Tags: svn

Tried committing to my SVN repository today but I'm getting a

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to   
Error: PUT request for '//!svn/wrk/36ffb5e7-878f-fa4e-9b5e-ce3415750884/.htaccess'
```

on one file which is my `.htaccess` file.  I've tried deleting from the repository but get a

```
Server sent unexpected return value (403 Forbidden) in response to PROPFIND request for '/.htaccess'
```

Please advise! It was working fine during my last commit.  Is this a permissions issue or something? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have access to the webserver log and can post the relevant output from that side?

Comment: Hmm where would I find this log? Running Ubuntu Server. Tried looking in apach2 log already

Comment: It was burried in error.log...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just posted the solution here: [Why won't svn let commit .htaccess files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574655/why-wont-svn-let-commit-htaccess-files)

Comment: Hi, I have same issue but we have .net Project and there is no .htaccess file, how can i solve this issue?

Comment: @vinitpatel assuming that you use IIS, you have to convert the rules to web.config ...as explained here: http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig

Answer (score 1):

You  can backup directory to other place,the use svn to delete the directory , then commint ,then copy the backup directory  to the original place， then use svn to add！

I just do these steps and solve the problem. I think maybe something is wrong to the svn xml structure.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Password is expired or not by Deleting the SVN credentials and try committing again. It worked for me follow the below steps.
In Windows system try

Type %APPDATA% in windows start and open the folder location. Navigate to svn.simple folder (Roaming -> Subversion -> auth -> svn.simple). Delete the file present in this folder. Move to eclipse, Right click on the Project, Team -> Cleanup. Now try committing.