# Unable to commit .htaccess file with subversion with ubuntu client

Tags: apache, .htaccess, svn, ubuntu-14.04

I can't commit an `.htaccess` file to a subversion server, using http protocol. Some tips about this issue:

- We can import this file when we are creating repository, but we can't
  commit changes to it.
- We can commit changes with a Tortoise client on a windows machine.
- We are not able to commit changes using command-line subversion client, on a ubuntu machine.

I made some googling and also looked the suggestions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574655/why-doesnt-subversion-allow-to-commit-htaccess-files) at stackoverflow, without sucess for now.

I have changed this apache directive:

```
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
     Order allow,deny
     Deny from all
</Files>
```

To:

```
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

But no success. Also I have change the AllowOverride directive to all, without success too.

Any suggestions are welcome,

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

After several test, we have finally solved this issue. We found that the subversion server has a older release (1.6.6) and we were trying to commmit with newer version of the subversion client (1.8.8).

We have done an subversion downgrade to the version 1.6.17 of the client, and it works.

Seems that there's some issue with the http client library change. In version 1.8.8 subversion uses serf library, instead of neon library user in early versions.

Thanks anyway.